# Split raw data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, cut

I want to cut the raw data from txt file by python. The raw data like this:

```
-0.156 200

-0.157 300

-0.158 400

-0.156 201

-0.157 305

-0.158 403

-0.156 199

-0.157 308

-0.158 401
```

I expect to extract the file to many txt file like this.

```
-0.156 200

-0.157 300

-0.158 400
```

---

```
-0.156 201

-0.157 305

-0.158 403
```

---

```
-0.156 199

-0.157 308

-0.158 401
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: What's the condition of splitting data, like each file will have 3 entries?

Comment: Yes, each file will contain the same x data but different y data.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried before coming to ask a question so we can help you solve your problem

Comment: `{f"df_{x}" : y for x,y in df.groupby(df.index // 3)}` ?

Answer (score 0):

This splits the data into files with three entries in each file

```py
READ_FROM = 'my_file.txt'

ENTRIES_PER_FILE = 3

with open(READ_FROM) as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    i = 1
    n = 1
    for line in data:
        with open(f'new_file_{n}.txt', 'a') as g:
            g.write(line + '\n')
            i += 1
        if i > ENTRIES_PER_FILE:
            i = 1
            n += 1
```

new_file_1.txt

```
-0.156 200
-0.157 300
-0.158 400
```

new_file_2.txt

```
-0.156 201
-0.157 305
-0.158 403
```

new_file_3.txt

```
-0.156 199
-0.157 308
-0.158 401
```

Comment: Is it possible if I plot a 3D surface (colormap) in Python (matplotlib) from many text files?

I have many txt file, each have x , y and z colomn. How can I plot 3D colormap surface by using Matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces between your lines and you want spaces between your lines in your new file this will work:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
cleaned_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if len(line.strip()) > 0]
num_lines_per_file = 3
for num in range(0, len(cleaned_lines), num_lines_per_file):
    with open(f'{num}.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in cleaned_lines[num:num + num_lines_per_file]:
            out_file.write(f'{line}\n\n')
```